# If-Else Statements using Boolean variables

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean

I was wondering about how the true/false values worked when inside If-Else statements?
Specifically, a prompt asks to check if a certain year is a leap year.
This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
   int inputYear;
   bool isLeapYear = false; //the prompt already sets bool isLeapyear = false

   cin >> inputYear;

   if (inputYear % 400 == 0) {
      isLeapYear = true;
   }
   else if ((inputYear % 4 == 0) && (inputYear % 100 != 0)) {
      isLeapYear = true;
   }
   else {
   }

   if (isLeapYear) {
      cout << inputYear <<  " is a leap year" << endl;
   }
   else {
      cout << inputYear << " is not a leap year" << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

When running this, all the inputs check out, but I noticed that if the boolean variable is initially isLeapYear=false, then how is it that for the second if-statement

```
if (isLeapYear) {
```

if an input like 50 (which obviously is not a leap year) skips all the if/if-else/else statements and runs into this second if-statement, and if isLeapYear is never set to true since the input didn't meet any conditions, wouldn't the if-statement turn into if (false) ... and then should actually output "50 - leap  year" ?

I essentially have the right code, but I'm confused on the logic as to why an incorrect/false input wouldn't also output to "is a leap year".

Comment: I'm confused why you think `if (false)` should execute the `if` branch and not the `else` branch. `if` evaluates the expression in brackets, if it evaluates to `true`, the `if-statement` is executed, if it evaluates to `false`, the `else-statement` is executed (if it's there of course).

Comment: `if (false) ... else ...` means the else branch is taken. For input 50 the output is  "is not a leap year"

Comment: you can try this by writing code with `if (false) { std::cout <<"false"; } else { std::cout << "true"; }`. What would you expect to be printed?

Comment: `50` is not "incorrect / false" input. Its a totally valid `int`. `isLeapYear` is not modified, it stays `false`, hence you get `"is not a leap year"` as output

Comment: OT: you should have `isLeapYear = inputYear % 400 == 0 || ((inputYear % 4 == 0) && (inputYear % 100 != 0))` instead of an if/else.

Comment: When you have "complex" conditions in an if statement just make a small function. So the whole logic of `is_leapyear` should not be a boolean but a function `bool is_leapyear(const unsigned year)` then you can write all the logic in that function and your main will only have an `if (is_leapyear(year))`. The code is immediately more readable and better you can make tests for your function.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1):

> if an input like 50 (which obviously is not a leap year) skips all the if/if-else/else statements and runs into this second if-statement, and if isLeapYear is never set to true since the input didn't meet any conditions, wouldn't the if-statement turn into if (false) ...

So far so good. Only a minor nitpick: The if/if-else/else is not "skipped". The onditions are evaluated they are both `false`, the `else` branch is taken (which is a noop).

You are right that `if (leapYear)` is equivalent to `if (false)` when `isLeapYear` was not assigned `true`.

> .. and then should actually output "50 - leap year" ?

This is the puzzling part of your analysis. Consider this simpler example:

```
#include <iostream>


bool isLeapYear() { return false; }

int main() {
    if (false) { std::cout << "this is not printed"; } 
    else { std::cout << "Hello ";}

    if (isLeapYear()) { std::cout << "this is not printed"; }
    else { std::cout << "leap year!";}
}
```

It prints

```
Hello leap year!
```

In the first if statement `if (false)` implies that the `else` branch is taken.

In the second part I illustrated how you can use a function to evaluate the condition and return the result. As a first test, my `isLeapYear` always returns `false`. Hence `if (isLeapYear())` is again equivalent to `if (false)` and the `else` branch is taken.